# Trouble updating file in main bundle

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsbundle

I have a weird problem. I have a `database` in `main bundle` in my app. When the app launches it checks whether there is a database in documents directory. If not, then it copies there from bundle. Everything was Working before I `update Xcode`. Now, when I try to delete an old database from bundle and to put the new one, it still copies the old. Eventhough I've put it into trash and cleaned trash. 
Can anyone suggest a solution? Because I'm a bit confused with it.

I tried some way and I found out that when I add a new file to the project - it just doesn't add there... Though in Xcode I see it in bundle....

Comment: Well..,Which xcode version u r using?

Comment: @Noobass If you could post some code ,then someone can easily help you.

Comment: I'm using 4.3.1 Xcode version

Comment: I tried it several times - didn't help

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the application from simulator or device. Your application in the simulator has already copied the database from main bundle to documents directory.

So, if you will reinstall the app, your new database will be installed.